# Nginx PHP7.0-FPM No such file or directory Ubuntu

Tags: php, nginx

I had nginx working right, then all of a sudden it started having permission issues on the html folder, so I edited the permission with

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`
But then I started having issues with the php7.0-fpm.sock
If I try to load the page first it says

> Unable to connect
>   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 5.**.****.**.

Then half of the time I get this:

> The connection was reset
>   The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

in nginx's error.log I get this:

> [crit] 23274#23274: *6335 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
>   failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

By running `ls -l /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`
I get:

```
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jun  5 13:37 /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

By running: `ls -l /var/www/html`
I get:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  108850 Jan 28 09:01 stuff.php
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
> root@webserver2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat default
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#

server {

 location /nginx_status {
          stub_status on;
          access_log   off;
          allow all;

        }

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;
        listen 127.0.0.1;
        server_name rightdomain.me;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404; rewrite ^/(.*)admin(.*)$ http://meatspin.fr/ redirect;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

update:
trying to connect from chrome gave me error 404 not found, so I looked the error.log and it said permission issue, switched back to root:root with chown and now it says again issue with the php7.0-fpm as not found

Comment: the php fast process manager needs to be running as it creates that socket file. does `systemctl status php7.0-fpm` say the process is active?

Comment: @castis  Active: active (running)

Comment: and you're starting nginx with `sudo systemctl start nginx`, right?

Comment: @castis service nginx start/stop

Comment: try `sudo systemctl start nginx`

Comment: @castis did so, tried also with same command to stop both, start the php-fpm first and nginx later but same thing. Maybe the issue has something to do with it switching from Cannot connect, to Connection was reset on every/every1-3 requests

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar error with nginx recently.

This is how I solved it:

1. Confirm that php-fpm is running. It was restarting in my case due to certain modules being installed. During fpm-restarts, nginx tried to connect and there's no fpm running.
2. Make sure that php-fpm and nginx have proper permission to the socket file.
3. In my case I later switched php-fpm from socket to port 9000.

Hope this helps.